# Gradient Checking: MeanSquareError. Why huge epsilon improves discrepancy?

Tags: gradient-descent, backpropagation, gradient

I am using custom C++ code, and coded a simple "Mean Squared Error" layer.
Temporarily using it for the 'classification task', not a simple regression. ...maybe this causes the issues?

I don't have anything else before this layer - not even a simple Dense layer. It's just MSE on its own.
Its input is a collection of rows of input features. For example, here are 8 rows of input features that will be passed to MSE all at once:

```
{ a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7 }
{ b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7 }
{ c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 }
{ d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7 }
{ e0, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7 }
{ f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7 }
{ g0, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7 }
{ h0, h1, h2, g3, h4, h5, h6, h7 }    //8x8 matrix (contains 64 different values)
```

Every row of this matrix gets passed into my "Mean Square Error" layer, returning a single scalar for such a row: "Cost".

I then compute a "final error" scalar, which is the average of such Costs.

When doing Gradient Checking, I am looking at how this "final error" quantity changes as I perturb each of the 64 input values, seen above. The idea is that the changes in `finalError` must correspond to the gradient computed by formula, with respect to my 64 input values. If they match, then I've coded backprop correctly.

Here is the forward prop:

$$finalError =   \frac{1}{r}\sum^r{  \left(  \frac{1}{2n}\sum^n{(input_i-target)^2} \right) }   $$

where $n$ is the number of features per row, and $r$ is the number of rows.

Here is the gradient wrt one of input values, that my backprop is using:

$$\frac{\partial finalError}{\partial input_i} = \frac{1}{rn}(input_i - target)$$

**Question:**

I peturb each input value 'up', then 'down', running forward prop 64*2 = 128 times. This gives me numerical estimate of gradient for my 64 input values.

**However this numerical estimate and the actual analytical gradient become less similar when *smaller* epsilon is used**. This is counterintuitive to me. On the contrary, my vectors match almost exactly, when I use a ridiculously large value for epsilon, such as $1$

Is this expected, or do I have an error in C++ code?

---

Here is the pseudocode

```
for every input value i:
   i -= EPSILON
   finalCost_down =  fwdprop( inputMatrix )//very simple - just computes final cost via MSE layer.  finalCost_down is a scalar.
   i += EPSILON
   finalCost_up   =  fwdprop( inputMatrix ) 
   gradientEstimate[i] = (finalCost_up - finalCost_down) / (2*EPSILON)

//after the loop, some time later, just one invocation of backprop:
trueGradientVec = backprop( vec )

//some time later:

discrepancyScalar =  (gradientEstimate - trueGradientVec).magnitude / gradientEstimate.magnitude + trueGradientVec.magnitude)

//somehow discrepancyScalar decreases the larger the EPSILON was used:
// discrepancy is 0.00275, if EPSILON is 0.0001
// discrepancy is 0.00025, if EPSILON is 0.001
// discrepancy is 2.198e-05, if EPSILON is 0.01
// discrepancy is 3.149e-06, if EPSILON is 0.1
// discrepancy is 2.751e-07, if EPSILON is 1
```

I would expect discrepancy to decrease when epsilon is decreased, because finer perturbations should give more precise slope estimate...

[Andrew NG explanation of GradientChecking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSYgJNX_84U&t=321s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by numerical precision of floating numbers. It becomes really apparent as we change one of input values, by a tiny $\epsilon$ which (in my example above) emedially affects the cost function.

The tricky thing was - because the cost function is Mean Square Error (MSE), and there are no other layers in my network, [we indeed can use any epsilon to estimate the slope](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3634059/147567). Even ridiculous epsilon will work, and will be numerically more stable, explaining why discrepancy seemed to get better. That's just how $y=x^2$ works.

In practice, when doing gradient-checking, I switched to another cost function, which is linear (instead of MSE). This improved the numerical stability, allowing me to use epsilon that is 10 times smaller:

$$C=\sum^r\sum^n(obtained-expected)$$

the gradient is then simply:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial (obtained)_{rn}} = 1$$

I don't use this cost in production, just for purpose of gradient-checking.

So yeah, this explains why large epsilon was improving the discrepancy.

---

**Edit:**

**Notice that this linear-cost function must not be used if you have a softmax right before it. That's because the sum of softmax is always 1.0**

**In that case you must use the MSE**